# Databind to className winjs

Tags: javascript, data-binding, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I have a `repeater` containing a button. The button's class should be set based on it's status.

How would I go about databinding the `State:` property to a CSS `className`?

### DATA

```
items = new WinJS.Binding.List([
    {
        JobOperations: [
            { AccountType: "Internal", Index: 1, Requirements: "Do something to something else", Rework: true, State: "onHold", LoadHours: "5.7" },
            { AccountType: "Retail", Index: 2, Requirements: "Watch something for a duration of time", Rework: true, State: "complete", LoadHours: "2.1" }
        ]
    }
]);
```

### HTML & BINDINGS

```
<div id="rptOperations" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" class="buttonList operationsList" data-win-options="{data: items}">
    <button data-win-bind="className: State" class="button">
        <span data-win-bind="textContent: Index" class="index">1/span>
        <span data-win-bind="textContent: Requirements" class="requirements"></span>
        <span data-win-bind="textContent: AccountType" class="accountType"></span>
        <span data-win-bind="textContent: LoadHours" class="loadHours"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

### Desired Output

*(Note the classes `onHold` and `complete` on the buttons)*

```
<div id="rptOperations" class="buttonList operationsList">
    <button class="button onHold">
        <span class="index">1</span>
        <span class="requirements">Do something to something else</span>
        <span class="accountType">Internal</span>
        <span class="loadHours">5.7</span>
    </button>
    <button class="button complete">
        <span class="index">2</span>
        <span class="requirements">Watch something for a duration of time</span>
        <span class="accountType">Retail</span>
        <span class="loadHours">2.1</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The code above is a dumbed down version for this example. Everything works perfectly in the actual app up until I try to bind to `className` which causes the app to crash.

If I can't do it this way, what would be the best way? I've done an extensive search on google before I posted this and cannot find much on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell without more code but I have seen people have problems in WinJS when they don't call Binding.processAll in their code

```js
app.onactivated = function (args) {

    // Other activation code ...

    var personDiv = document.querySelector('#nameSpan');
    WinJS.Binding.processAll(personDiv, person);
    var bindingSource = WinJS.Binding.as(person);
}
```

In general you can resolve most of the issues referencing these two tutorials but if you feel you have gotten this all correct, we need some more code to help!  Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700358.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh700356.aspx

In your case you can define a namespace and your data as follows:

```js
 "use strict";
    WinJS.Namespace.define("MyAppData", {
        items: new WinJS.Binding.List([
           { AccountType: "Internal", Index: 1, Requirements: "Do something to something else", Rework: true, State: "onHold", LoadHours: "5.7" },
            { AccountType: "Retail", Index: 2, Requirements: "Watch something for a duration of time", Rework: true, State: "complete", LoadHours: "2.1" }
        ])
    });
```

Then wire this to your controls like this:

```js
 <div id="rptOperations" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Repeater" class="buttonList operationsList" data-win-options="{data: MyAppData.items}">
        <button data-win-bind="className: State" class="button">
            <span data-win-bind="textContent: Index" class="index"></span>
            <span data-win-bind="textContent: Requirements" class="requirements"></span>
            <span data-win-bind="textContent: AccountType" class="accountType"></span>
            <span data-win-bind="textContent: LoadHours" class="loadHours"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've pasted all the code that I have for this and I've updated the question with a desired output. Ideally I want the `State` property in the data to become the class of the repeated button template.

Comment: I have the same problem, it is not so much a problem with a binding not working, the question is how do you bind to the css class property.